# SSDT Create schema if not exists

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I am developing sql project using ssdt in vs2017. I want to create new schema only if it doesn't exist. I have to create new schema otherwise I cannot build my project.

The project that I am developing doesn't have specific db so I cannot do schema comparison. The built sql scipt will be called within other application, and the target db will be selected from the application

Regards,

Comment: Consider having the app invoke sqlpackage.exe or Dacfx objects to generate the deployment script. That will be easier than idempotent scripts to build the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
use YourDB
go

if schema_id('YourSchema') is null
    exec ('create schema YourSchema')
```

Although if possible, try to avoid doing that in an ETL package and instead in however the DB is deployed/maintained.

Comment: I create new schema by adding new item -> Security -> Schema in VS which only allow DDL not DML so I cannot put the if statement in there. If I create new schema in pre-deployment script, then build I got the following error "SQL71501: ... has an unresolved reference to Schema"